# Is it possible to assign jinja variable to id of an anchor tag without using javascript only in html?

Tags: html, django, jinja2

**HTML**
I have assigned pid with a1 and wish to give id="a1" using jinja variable pid.

```
    {%with pid='a1' %} 
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="{{pid}}" >Google</a>
    {%endwith%}
```

Comment: The `{% endwith %}`, should be put *below* the use of `{{ pid }}`.

Comment: thank u but my problem didn't solve though

Answer (score 3):

**You can refer to this code.**

```
{% for comp in Companies %} # Companies is one of the tables
<div id="company_{{ comp.id }}"> 
{{ comp.establish_date }}
{{ comp.name }}
</div>
<button onClick="toggleDiv("company_{{ comp.id }}")">Show Content</button>
```